# CSS: Getting my sidebar to not be on top of my other content

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I'm currently trying to make it such that my sidebar (shown in the picture) doesn't display *on top* of my map. I would like them to be side-by-side but not quite sure of how to do it with the css.
[image]
This is what it looks like inside the inspector
[image]

I would appreciate any help! I've been stuck on this for a little while now :-(

I've tried remove z-index but that just hides the sidebar

EDIT: How I'm calling these components (both are from libraries)

```
class DashboardView extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    return <div>
        <div>
          <Sidebar />
        </div>
        <div>
          <Map />
        </div>
    </div>;
  }
}
```

EDIT2: Here is the map's styles. Adding `margin-left: 64px` solves the problem but is there another alternative where I don't have to hardcode `64px`?
[image]

Comment: Can you provide more of your code? Preferably the HTML to create the menu and map as well as more CSS?

Comment: And also please provide the code as **text** so we can copy-paste it and test it ourselves; looking at an image of code makes debugging it much more difficult. Having said that, the issue is almost certainly with `z-index`.

Comment: @BryceHowitson The sidebar css is actually a package from https://github.com/trendmicro-frontend/react-sidenav and the Map is from https://github.com/fullstackreact/google-maps-react#readme.

Comment: you can state `margin-left: 64px` for map container to avoid overlapping

Comment: @Banzay Thanks, that is a good solution but is there another solution in which I don't have to hardcode `margin-left: 64px` in the case that I want everything to be dynamically sized?

Comment: It seems that there's no single solution. It depends on context. E.g. you can set `float: left` for both of divs but I'm not sure that suits for your case. Or you can use `flex` alignment. Looks like a simplest way  to set `position: relative` for sidebar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you specified `position:absolute` and thus the object(your sidenav) will be placed to the exact position that you specified(top:0; left:0 and so on). removing css position property and adding float:left might solve your problem. I cant give you the exact solution because you didn't share your HTML code. See the following example and try to add `position : absolute` to the first `div` tag:

```html
<div style="float:left;top:0; width: 100px;height: 100px; background-color: yellow">float left</div>
<div style="float:left; width: 100px;height: 100px; background-color: green">float left</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the wrapper HTML this is just a guess...

HTML needs a wrapper (could be body)

```
<div id="mapContainer">
   <div id="sidebar">Sidebar</div>
   <div id="map">Map</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#mapContainer {
   display:flex;
}
#sidebar {
   flex: 1;
}
#map {
   flex: 9;
}
```

Also REMOVE these from sidebar nav as they'll defeat the flexbox

```
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
bottom: 0;
```

Answer (score -1):

if you are using bootstrap then the following code will help:

```
 class DashboardView extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
      }
      render() {
        return <div className="row">
            <div className="col-md-3">
              <Sidebar />
            </div>
            <div className="col-md-9">
              <Map />
            </div>
        </div>;
      }
    }
```

Comment: I've tried using `display: flex` which I think attempts to accomplish the same thing here but to no avail :-(

Comment: @tim Flexbox should work but you probably need to remove `position: absolute` from the nav as well.